# .htaccess redirects wrong on specific 'words'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know there are a few questions about this type of problems, but with them i couldn't figure out whats wrong with mine..

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

<FilesMatch "admin.php">
    AuthName "Member Only"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile D:/web/shorten/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

**filesystem**

```
shorten
    - .htaccess
    - .htpasswd
    - admin.php
    - index.php
```

So, the plan is to rewrite everything alphanumeric to index.php?id=stuff - works fine. but somehow it does stuff wrong when the regex matches the word *admin*. The result I'm getting is *admin/?id=admin* - which of course, leads to a 404.

Accessing admin.php directly works fine, as expected, with auth and everything.

It seems like it has a problem with the existing admin.php, but why and how to avoid this?

Comment: when you are writing admin in url it is passing `index.php?id=admin` and when you are passing admin.php it is working fine so i think you have to check what you should do when id is having value admin, that's what i get.

Comment: for now, index just prints the value of id, no processing for now. but if it works for you i guess its something with my apache settings? EDIT: read your comment wrong - the problem is it does not pass admin via `?id=admin`, it just does some weird redirect to `admin/?id=admin`.

Comment: Check if you have `MultiViews` enabled on in your Apache settings. If you do, try to disable it with: `Options -MultiViews.`. If Apache doesn't find a file (in your case `admin`) and MultiViews is enabled, Apache will look in the folder for any file with that name. In your case `admin.*` (which you do have).

Comment: `MultiViews` is not in the options for this directory (or any other, for that matter).

Comment: Try to explicitly disable it anyway, in case it's globally set. Might not be the issue, but trail'n'error. (had a very similar issue recently where disabling it did solve it) :)

Comment: did a quick search for it in httpd.conf, adding it gave me a different result - it found admin.php as you said, so i guess we can say it isn't activated somewhere?

Comment: as far as i can see the default configuration doesnt activate it anyway, it even needs to be listed next to `All` to use it, a comment tells me in there.:o

Comment: Weird. Just tested with your set up and if I disable MultiViews, it works, but if I add it, I get the same error as you. Can you post your vhost settings?

Comment: i'm not really confident with the apache settings, i've set it up with xampp at the moment, so i guess you need the httpd.conf or am i wrong there?

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure how XAMPP handles vhost so I'm not sure where they keep vhost settings or what the default settings are.

Comment: found the httpd-vhosts.conf, i guess that's it. but everything in there is commented out, so no rules from there..

Comment: went through all the configs, and the only 2 times `MultiViews` makes an appearance is for some icon directory of xampp and my user-directory. user is on another drive and the icon directory has a completely different path, so it shouldn't affect my working-dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny story..

Chrome (eventually other browsers too) cache redirects. As far as I read that's just for the 301 ones, but it seems like all of them are cached.

So the weird redirect was just a wrong one caused by fiddling around with redirects.

Thanks for trying to help me anyways. :)

Comment: going to mark this as correct as soon as possible, SO appearantly wants me to check my facts for 2 days..